# How to send Progress from library on Android?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a project: **myApp**
these files...
- **myFragment**.java.
- **myDialogFragment**.java.
- **myAsyncTask**.java

I have a project: **myLibrary**
This project "is Library" of "myApp"
I have...
- **myMethodsToUpload**.java

One of these methods, have a While bucle for write the file on php server.
Everything works like magic! :)
and the reason for the file structure is to make the library reusable.
but...

How can I send the increments of a value inside of this While bucle, to myAsyncTask.java?
Considering that...
what I want to do... is to make "myMethodsToUpload.java", reusable.

Some code...

**myFragment.java**

```
    myDialogFragment df = new myDialogFragment();
    df.setMyThings(new myAsynctask(), myParameters);
    df.setTargetFragment(this, 0);
    df.show(getFragmentManager(), DIALOG_FRAGMENT_TAG);
```

.
**myDialogFragment.java**

```
public class myDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    myAsyncTask async;
    public void setMyThings(myAsynctask inAsynctask, String[] inArray){
        async = inAsynctask;
        async.sendFragment(this);
        parameters = inArray;
    }
    //...  

    //Only called from "myAsyncTask.java"
    public void updateFromAsyncTask(Integer porcent){
        progressbar.setProgress(porcent);
    }
    //...  

}
```

.
**myAsyncTask.java**

```
public class myAsynctask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    void sendFragment(myDialogFrament inFragment){
        myDialogFrament = inFragment;
    }
    //...

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... inArray) {
        String urlPHP = inArray[0];
        String pathImg = inArray[1];
        String paramValue = inArray[2];
        String msj = "";

        try {
            methodsToUpload up = new methodsToUpload(urlPHP);
            up.connectNow();
            up.insertFile(pathImg);
            up.insertParams("pName", paramValue);
            up.insertFinish();
            msj = up.coonectClose();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return msj;
    }

    //Called from "myMethods.java"  
    public void updateFromAsyncTask(int porcent){
        publishProgress(porcent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... inPorcent) {
        if(myDialogFragment == null){
            return;
        }
        myDialogFragment.updateFromAsyncTask(inPorcent[0]);
    }
}
```

.
**myMethodsToUpload.java**

```
public class myMethodsToUpload {
    //...  

    public myMethodsToUpload(String url_in){
        this.url = url_in;
    }

    public void insertFile(String path) throws Exception {
        //...
        //...

        while (bytesRead > 0) {
            salidaStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            sendedPorcent += bytesRead;
            completedPorcent = (int) (sendedPorcent * 100 / fileSize);

            //This line doesn't work...
            //because myAsyncTask.java, is in another project.
            myAsyncTask.updateFromAsyncTask(completedPorcent);

            bytesAvailable = archivoStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = archivoStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
         }

        //...
        //...
    }

}
```

.
I've already tried...
"MyLibrary" -> propeties -> java build path -> projects -> add -> Project(myApp)
but...
throws me errors:
W/System.err(32469): at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)...
ThreadPoolExecutor.runworker...
etc.
And, in the status bar of eclipse appears every moment "Building Workspace (X%)"

I'm a newbie, but I think the error happens because "MyLibrary" is Library of "MyApp", and I'm trying use "java build path".
So... how can I resolve this?, I'm lost!!!

sorry by my english... thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I already got -1, thanks but can I know what I need to improve this question?, I've researched a lot and that is why I can explain it, I try be clear, but if I'm not... would be great some clues!

Comment: first of all you should avoid using asynctask, better use IntentService. If you want to have a "callback" i would say you have 3 simple solutions. Create an Interface and use it as a callback - use LocalBroadcast - Use an EventBus

Comment: I think I'll use IntentService for files bigger than 300Kb. Thanks anyway. And I know to use/create Callbacks, but my problem is that my Library Project, creates a value, and I need pass it to my main project. (as mencioned above). If any helps...?

Comment: To pass Object through Intents you can use Parcelable. For simple datas just serialize it. What type is your value ?

Comment: the data type is a simple "int"... My libraryProject has a class that set a int value. I need pass this value to my MainProject Asynctask to update the progressBar. I know how to do it with a counter + asynctask + progress bar in one file.java. the problem is when I try to do in separate files and projects.

Comment: the intention is to learn more about how to pass values ​​generated by classes in the library in loops to the main project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple exemple :

**Your AsyncTask class :**

```
private CallBack mCallback;

public static interface CallBack {
    public void updateValue(int value);
}

public void setCallBack(CallBack callBack){
    this.mCallBack = callBack;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... inPorcent) {
    mCallback.updateValue(inPorcent[0].intValue());
}
```

**Your fragment class :**

```
public class Fragment extends Fragment implements Callback {

    private AsyncTask yourAsyncTask;
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        yourAsyncTask = new AsyncTask();
        yourAsyncTask.setCallBack(this);
        yourAsyncTask.excecute();
    }

   @Override
    public void updateValue(int value){
        Log.e(TAG,"Value : " + value);
    }
}
```

EDIT 1 :

```
public class AdsHttpRequest {

    private static final String     TAG     = AdsHttpRequest.class.getSimpleName(); // log
    private GetHttpTask             mGetAsyncTask;
    private static AdsHttpRequest   mInstance;
    private OnGetRequestListener    mCallBack;
    private static final String     SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String     SUCCES  = "succes";
    private static final String     FAILED  = "fail";

    /**
     * @return a singleton instance of {@link AdsHttpRequest}
     */
    public static AdsHttpRequest getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            synchronized (AdsHttpRequest.class) {
                if (mInstance == null) {
                    mInstance = new AdsHttpRequest();
                }
            }
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the {@link AsyncTask}, set the callback, execute the task
     * 
     * @param url
     *        url for the request
     * @param callback
     *        {@link OnGetRequestListener} for feed back
     */
    public void post(String url, OnGetRequestListener callback) {
        mCallBack = callback;
        if (mGetAsyncTask == null) {
            mGetAsyncTask = new GetHttpTask();
        } else {
            cancelGetTask();
            mGetAsyncTask = new GetHttpTask();
        }
        mGetAsyncTask.execute(url);
    }

    /**
     * cancel the {@link AsyncTask} if it's still alive <br>
     * <b>see </b> {@link Status}
     */
    public void cancelGetTask() {
        if (mGetAsyncTask != null && mGetAsyncTask.getStatus().equals(Status.RUNNING)) {
            mGetAsyncTask.cancel(true);
        }
        mGetAsyncTask = null;
    }

    private AdsHttpRequest() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Actually construct and launch the HTTP request
     * 
     * @param url
     *        url of the request
     * @return response of the server
     */
    private String getResponseFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "", e);
        }
        return xml;
    }

    /**
     * Manage the http request in background
     * 
     * @param String
     *        url for the request
     */
    private class GetHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            if (params[0] != null) {
                return getResponseFromUrl(params[0]); // return the response of the server
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result != null) {
                if (result.contains(SUCCES) || result.contains(SUCCESS)) {
                    mCallBack.onGetRequestResult(SUCCESS);
                } else {
                    mCallBack.onGetRequestResult(FAILED);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help, but the problem is that the value is generated in a library project and AsyncTask is in another (main) project. What you did, I've done in separate classes in the same project. but it is not the case.

Comment: So you tell me that you have this  :  Library -> AsyncTask -> Fragment. Then why not use the same process between library and asynctask ?

Comment: MyProject -> Fragment -> AsyncTask. and the other project: LibraryProject -> methods that handle HttpURLConnection.

Comment: When you try import com.mainproject.myAsyncTask on MethodsInLibray, it doesn't work. I guess it's because the LibraryProject, is set as "is Library", in "MainProject" (I just guess)

Comment: of course it does not work. This is two diferent project. I think you are trying to do things in the wrong order. What i said in my previous message is the order in which the data is passed. Your Lib does the work in the method, if you create an interface in your lib the idea is to CALL the interface from your main project. You should NEVER concider importing class from your main project into your Lib "import com.mainproject.myAsyncTask on MethodInLibray" never do things like that.

Comment: Ups... well I was thinking something like that but I wasn't sure... let me try with your callbacks...

Comment: i was editing my answer but it is not good. What you should do is move your asyncTask into your lib, use it from there. Just like a Service would work from a separate thread your async task is highly coupled with the http request. You should also move you Http request into your asynctask. See my edit it may help

Comment: That was the first thing that I thought but I want methods for httpURLConnection for reuse later... but is not recomended then?

Comment: Add a class in your lib that manages only the HttpURLConnection, a class that does the process/get url from mainProject. Your process class should do the work, use the HttpURLConnection class which contain the async task (cause you must do httprequest on separate thread) your main project should only, use the process class from the lib, implement the callback to get result in order to update the UI. That's all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60679/discussion-between-arickdev-and-julien-m).

Answer (score 0):

The way that I'm doing this consume more memory, time, threads? (I'm guessing)

Comment: Using IOStream or file writting can be heavy on cpu and memory

Comment: I think I got it, my pc connection is fail, now I'm only the phone, I'll try your example and I'll write later...